# Compare two python codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

I've been solving Euler project problems, it's the forth one now (we should find the largest palindrome number made from the product of 3-digit numbers.

Anyone knows why the first code works properly, but the second one doesn't?
First:

```
highest = 0
product = 0
def PalDetect(number):
    return str(number) == str(number)[::-1]

ThreeDigits = [i for i in range(100, 1000)]

for i in ThreeDigits:
    for j in ThreeDigits:
        product = i*j
        if (PalDetect(product)) and (product > highest):
            highest = product 

print(highest)
```

Second:

```
product = 0
def PalDetect(number):
    return str(number) == str(number)[::-1]

ThreeDigits = [i for i in range(100, 1000)]
for i in ThreeDigits:
    for j in ThreeDigits:
        if PalDetect(i*j):
            product = i*j

print(product)
```

I expected the second one works properly, and I still don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: Improve formatting

Comment: Second doesn’t have `and (product > highest):` so you find another one that is a lower product after the highest one and overwrite it. Print palindromes as you find them and debug yourself.

Comment: tip: if you loop from high to low you will need less iterations. If you found lets say that 978 * 988 is a solution there's no need to check if 55*170 is a solution. You can finish the loops earlier and save a lot of iterations. But be careful when pruning, there can be solutions where one of the element is lower than the best_so_far while the other one is higher.

Comment: @Elerium115 so i loop (1000→100) & j loop should be (1000→i) + whenever got palindrome break a second loop only
[2nd option] j loop (1000→(highest/i)) also feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 1 updates the highest variable only if the product is a palindrome and greater than the current highest. This ensures that it finds the largest palindrome.
Code 2 updates product to every palindrome it encounters, regardless of its value compared to previous palindromes. This means it only prints the last palindrome found, which might not be the largest.

Modify Code 2 to track and update the highest palindrome similar to Code 1:

```
highest = 0
product = 0

def PalDetect(number):
    return str(number) == str(number)[::-1]

ThreeDigits = [i for i in range(100, 1000)]

for i in ThreeDigits:
    for j in ThreeDigits:
        product = i * j
        if PalDetect(product) and product > highest:
            highest = product

print(highest)
```